# tightest bounds algorithm search

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for an algorithm that gets sorted array of n int and int x, `while A[1]<=x<=A[n]` but not has to be in the array, and return a pair (ub,lb) when `lb ≥ x ≥ ub` are the tightest bounds.

Anyone know something like that?

Comment: Show your existing code.  If you don't have anything, then start by trying to write the code, then revert back with any specific issues you're facing.

Comment: Do a binary search. Depending on your implementation, this will give the greatest smaller or smallest larger element (or the element itself in case the element is in the array). The bounds can be found by some `+1` and `-1` on the indices.